# Nuxt custom error page doesn't load for uncaught errors

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I'm trying to use a custom error page in Nuxt (see: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/views/#error-page).

I've created `layouts/error.vue`, but this page doesn't load for uncaught exceptions, for example:

```html
<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    component() {
      return () => import(`./non-existent-component.vue`);
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

When this error occurs server-side, I see the standard production error page. Is there a way to catch this in a generic way so that my custom error page loads in that instance?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to add such thing into your nuxt.config? export default {
  layout: {
    error: 'layouts/error'
  },

Comment: @ByteBrawler0 there is no "layout' property in nuxt config. Do you have docs to what you're referring to?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [nuxt documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/views#error-page), the error page is not shown while server side rendering. It's only used when a client side error occurs:

> The error page is a page component which is always displayed when an error occurs (**that does not happen while server-side rendering**).

A possible solution is to use the `errorMiddleware` hook when rendering. There you can catch unhandled server errors and redirect to an error page:

```js
// nuxt.config.js
hooks: {
  render: {
    errorMiddleware(app) {
      app.use((error, req, res) => {
        res.writeHead(500, {
          Location: '/my-error-page',
        });
        res.end();
      })
    },
  },
},
```

But you have to create the `my-error-page` myself in any case.

Comment: Thanks @kapcash. For some reason i see the `Location` header, but the browser isn't redirecting... I'm trying to debug this.

Comment: Try with 307 status code instead of 500?

Comment: I've tried `307`, `400`, `404`, `301`, doesn't seem to help.